# Array of linked lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list

This is from an exercise I've done:

We want to implement a priority queue system to plan the execution of the system processes. An array of MAXPRI represents the priorities of the system, where 0 is the highest priority and MAXPRI-1 is the lowest priority.  Each position i in the array will contain a dynamic linked list where the first element of this is the priority i process that must be executed (provided there are no processes available in the previous i-1 positions). Implement the following operations:

Create. Initialize array.

AddProcess. Given a priority and a process identifier, it adds the process to the end of the corresponding list.

ExecuteProcess. Remove from the list the most priority process. If there are no processes to execute, it will be indicated with a warning message.

Search. Given a process identifier it returns the priority of this one. If the id of the process does not exist, -1 will be returned.

Display. Go through the structure to show the existing processes that are available for execution sorted by priority (highest first).

[main.c](https://pastebin.com/yAqSPVsU), [linkedListArray.c](https://pastebin.com/vBZ5FFwD), [linkedListArray.h](https://pastebin.com/mKw9prs1)

```
#include "linkedListArray.h"

void Create(Node **queue)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXPRI; i++) {
        queue[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void Push(Node **queue, int pri, int id)
{
    Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new_node != NULL) {
        new_node->id = id;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        if (queue[pri] == NULL) {
            queue[pri] = new_node;
        }
        else {
            Node *aux = queue[pri];
            while (aux->next != NULL) {
                aux = aux->next;
            }
            aux->next = new_node;
        }
    }
}

void Execute(Node **queue)
{
    bool end = false;
    int i = 0;

    while (!end && i < MAXPRI) {
        if (queue[i] != NULL) {
            Node *aux = queue[i];
            queue[i] = queue[i]->next;
            free(aux);
            end = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (!end) {
        printf("There are no processes\n");
    }
}

int Search(Node **queue, unsigned int id)
{
    int pri = -1;
    Node *aux;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXPRI  &&  pri == -1; ++i) {
        aux = queue[i];
        while (aux != NULL  &&  pri == -1) {
            if (aux->id == id) {
                pri = i;
            }
            else
                aux = aux->next;
        }
    }
    return pri;
}

void Output(Node *head)
{
    for (Node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        if (current->next != NULL)
            printf ("%d -> ", current->id);
        else
            printf ("%d", current->id);
    }
}

void Display(Node **queue)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXPRI; i++) {
        printf ("Priority queue %d: ", i);
        Output(queue[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- An `if` clause of `Output` is only executed once, on the very first node. You may avoid this logic altogether by making it explicit:

  ```
  if (!head)
      return;
  printf("%d", head->id);

  for (head = head->next; head; head = head->next) {
      printf(" -> %d", head->id);
  }
  ```

  A missing

  ```
  printf("\n");
  ```

  seems like a bug (I hope it is a copy-paste error).
- An early `return` helps to avoid unnecessary variables. Consider `Search`:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < MAXPRI; i++)
      for (Node * aux = queue[i]; aux; aux = aux->next) {
          if (aux->id == id) {
              return i;
          }
      }
  }
  return -1;
  ```

  A perk benefit is that now you can rename meaningless `i` to a more reasonable `pri`.

  Similarly, if `Execute` returns as soon as a process is found, you wouldn't need `bool end`.
- I strongly recommend to factor the

  ```
      while (aux->next != NULL) {
          aux = aux->next;
      }
  ```

  loop into a function (say, `get_tail`), and streamline `Push`:

  ```
  Node * node = new_node(id);
  Node * tail = get_tail(pri);
  if (tail) {
      tail->next = node;
  } else {
      queue[pri] = node;
  }
  ```
- Using extra memory may significantly reduce the run time. In your case, the

  ```
  struct list {
      Node * head;
      Node * tail;
  };
  ```

  would reduce looking for tail complexity from linear to \$O(1)\$.
- `linkedListArray.h` shall only export the names defined in `linkedListArray.c`. The `#include` files required for `linkedListArray.c` compilation should be included directly in `linkedListArray.c`.